# NodeJS Activedirectory package leaks sockets on Unix

Tags: node.js, active-directory, redhat

First let me start off by saying I am not a NodeJS or Unix expert (.Net and Windows are my forte), so excuse me if I am asking questions that I should know the answers to.

For a project I am working on we are using a NodeJs server that is using the activedirectory package. We call into the AD / LDAPS server to get the user and verify some of the attributes. Here is the code in question:

```
var adConfig = {
    url: "ldaps://" + adServer,
    baseDN: "DC=ad,DC=onsemi,DC=com",
    username: config.ldaps_username,
    password: config.ldaps_password,
    tlsOptions: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
};

var ad = new activeDirectory(adConfig);
ad.findUser(userId, true, (error, user) => {
    ...
}
```

For every 10 runs, this code appears to leak about 150 sockets. I examined the open sockets via the "lsof | grep node" command and this is the type of new additions I get from the initial baseline call:

```
node      14493 14498      mesiapp  mem       REG              253,2    105824   2101177 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
node      14493 14498      mesiapp  mem       REG              253,2     31408   2101165 /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
node      14493 14498      mesiapp  mem       REG              253,2     61624   2101167 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so

node      14493 14497      mesiapp   25u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395132 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   26u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395133 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   27u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395134 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   28u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395135 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   29u     sock                0,7       0t0 312392286 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   30u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395136 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   31u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395137 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   32u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395138 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   33u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395139 protocol: TCP
node      14493 14497      mesiapp   34u     sock                0,7       0t0 312395141 protocol: TCP
```

These descriptors never get reclaimed and eventually we run out of them. This only appears to happen on our Redhat linux server. When I run the server on a Mac the file descriptors don't increase on each call.

I am looking for assistance on any additional debugging strategies to find where the leak is coming from. I can't find any more verbose lsof settings, and I've looked through the activedirectory js code as much as I can and can't find any direct sockets that are being used. And unfortunately that code is 4 years old and hasn't been updated and I can't get a hold of the original author, or find another package that works via LDAPS with a Windows AD server from NodeJS.

Any assistance or suggestions would be helpful. Running Node v11.12.0, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux v7.6, kernel v3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64

Comment: Have you seen the [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) package? It's a fork of the [activedirectory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory) package, but still maintained.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I tested it with that package and still an issue. I am leaning towards guessing that it might be a server issue rather than a code issue, but I am far from knowledgeable on Unix, so no clue on where to start there. The same issue can be replicated on two different unix servers.

Comment: You could always [open an issue](https://github.com/jsumners/node-activedirectory/issues) on GitHub and see if the maintainer has any ideas.